# dd-wrt on Linksys wrt1900acs v2 Not Giving access to Internet

Tags: router, vpn, routing, internet-connection, dd-wrt

ultimately I am looking to have my dd-wrt router provide vpn access (using StrongVPN) to all devices that connect to it.  Others (not requiring VPN) will connect to my carrier-provided vdsl router/wifi.  My main router is on 192.168.1.1.

I bought a linksys wrt1900acs v2, connected the wan port to my existing router, configured it and tested it (all with the linksys oem firmware) - all good.

I then flashed it with r35531 successfully.  It made me change the main username and password and allowed me to modify the wifi settings (only changed the name and password, left them as AP-mode).  I am able to change the the IP address (and dhcp) of the local lan ports/wifi.  I tried 192.168.1.x/24 without overlapping with the main routher.  I tried 192.168.2.1/24, etc...

The wan port successfully gets an IP address from my main router (192.168.1.60), but never allowed my pc (wired or wireless) internet access through the dd-wrt router.

I figure I need to get the basic functionality working before I tackle the VPN bit.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you have this setup for double NAT, you most likely want it in a bridge configuration.

plug the Uplink cable into a LAN port of the second router.

under setup --> basic setup sub-tab.

- Disable the WAN interface. (you can assign it to the switch)
- Disable DHCP on the second router. give it a LAN address of 192.168.1.254
  (assuming router-1 is at 192.168.1.1)
- Choose the DHCP forwarder option, pointing to the first routers address.

under security, disable the spi firewall.

save apply & reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... very cool. Thank you. I may try this. 
In the meantime I:
1. Assigned a fixed IP to the WAN of 192...230/24
2. Went into my Vodafone (Huawei) router and set (a) reserved .230, and (b) set .230 as an “exposed host” and kept the sd-wrt as a gateway (router didn’t work).  That got my internet routing working.

Then the trick was how to get the StrongVPN account working - I tried a bunch of things I found, but ultimately, the folks from SteingVPN helped me. They have an installer specifically for dd-wrt router (one command line) that pulls a script and automatically completes the Services VPN OpenVPN fields with everything that is required. The one trick that they didn’t know was that, it doesn’t automatically Save, Apply and reboot. You need to do that manually.

Cheers all.

I hope this experience helps someone!!